# Several associations between rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am struggling to define some relations in rails 4.2.4. At this moment I have the following:

```
class Artist
  has_many :artist_members, dependent: :destroy
end

class ArtistMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

Now I would like to add a new relationship to `ArtistMember` to link them to other Artists with attribute `linked_profiles`, which should resolve the id and the name of the Artist. These links should only be visible from this Artist and therefore I do not use many-to-many relationship.

I tried lots of stuff such as adding a new has_many relationship to ArtistMember like this:

```
#ArtistMember
has_many :linked_profiles, class_name: "Artist"
```

I am also struggling with the migration, any help on that would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is a "self-referential many-to-many relation".

As a starting point you could try this solution:

Models

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_members
  has_many :artists, through: :artist_members,
                     source:  :colleague
end

class ArtistMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :colleague, class_name: "Artist"
end
```

Migrations

```
class CreateArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :artists do |t|
      t.string  :name
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :artists
  end
end

class CreateArtistMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :artist_members do |t|
      t.integer :artist_id
      t.integer :colleague_id
      t.timestamps
    end  
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :artist_members
  end
end
```

end

Footnote: This is a solution Chad Fowler came up with in his Rails Recipes book.

EDIT

Now you can use it like so

```
joe = Artist.create(name: "Joe")
jane = Artist.crate(name: "Jane")
joe.artists << jane
```

EDIT

In the rails console `rails c`

```
> joe = Artist.create(name: "Joe")
> jane = Artist.crate( name: "Jane")
> joe.artists << jane
> ben  = Artist.crate(name: "Ben")
> joe.artists << ben
```

Now to retrieve only Jane

```
> joe.artists.where(name: "Jane")
Artist Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" INNER JOIN  
"artist_members" ON "artists"."id" = "artist_members"."colleague_id" 
WHERE "artist_members"."artist_id" = ? AND "artists"."name" = ?  
[["artist_id", 1], ["name", "Jane"]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Artist id: 2, name: "Jane", 
art: nil, created_at: "2015-11-11 18:40:12", updated_at: "2015-11-11 
18:40:12">]>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good start indeed. With this example I am able to store an integer in colleague_id. I do that just by posting the id of the artist as `colleague_id`.

So, how could I resolve this id to also include name? I guess I need to add something else to the model?

Comment: It works with `joe.artists`. However, I have still 2 questions to get it work. 1) At this moment, we can only set one colleague. 2) How to limit `joe.artists` to get only certain fields instead of everything.
Your help is very appreciated

Comment: I corrected colleagues to artists. Regarding your question 1) I am able to add more than 1 artist_member and added it in the example. To your question 2) I am not quite sure what you want to achieve. I have added an example to select only one of the artist_members. If that's not it just more precisely describe what you want to do.

Comment: I solved 2) by the following: `has_many :artists, -> { select "name" }, through: :artist_members, source: :colleague`.
I think you don''t really understand what I want. I know it is possible to have more `.artists`. However I need an artist_member to have more artists. At this moment it only can have one. I think I will need to change `belngs_to` relationship. I will check it out more tomorrow.